# Angular material2 theme customization using less preprocessor or plain css

Tags: angular, less, material-design, angular-material2

Is it possible to customize theme using less/plain css?
Had a look at few options and all of them suggest using scss

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819339/what-is-the-best-way-to-style-using-angular-2-material-design#40820776)
- [material2 github](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming-your-components.md)
- [Official doc](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme)

Since our proj. is already built in less, cannot switch to scss. 
Have tried to set the background color of mat-primary class but as expected - it does not work. PFB image - toolbar background looks fine, but all form input fields too turn into the same color
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try with SCSS and then compile the SCSS file to CSS?